# how to implement Resampling mean of dataframe object such that zero values are excluded in calculation of mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

I have a dataframe with timestamp values. I have been able to figure out how to use resample method of dataframe and applying function last() or mean() to results. I am doing it as follows :

```
print(type(df.timestamp))
print(type(df.timestamp[0]))
df=df.set_index('timestamp')
df_1=df.resample('60S').last()
df_2=df.resample('60S').mean()

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

Here, df_1 gives me result where values are last values in each resampling period and df_2 gives me result where values are mean of all values in each resampling period.

Now the issue is my data contains lots of zero values, so I want result of df_1 to contain last non-zero value and result of df_2 to contain mean of only those values which are non-zeros. I have not been able to figure out method to do so in the documentation([resampling link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.2/reference/resampling.html)).

Please suggest appropriate way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zero` can be replaced with `np.nan` and then functions can be applied.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp':pd.date_range('2020.01.01', periods=6, freq='30S'),
    'val':[1,2,3,0,0,4]
})
df=df.set_index('timestamp')
df.val = df.val.replace(0, np.nan)
df = df.resample('60s').agg(['mean','last'])
df
```

**Output**

```
                      val
                      mean     last
timestamp       
2020-01-01 00:00:00   1.5       2.0
2020-01-01 00:01:00   3.0       3.0 
2020-01-01 00:02:00   4.0       4.0
```